# Lambda expression in Android Studio

Tags: java, lambda, beacon, android-studio-2.3, android-ibeacon

Currently, I am running a project that requires me to build an Android application using Android Studio version 2.3 to detect the Estimote Beacon in range. I had followed several tutorials from the internet to build the code and when I wanted to test run the code, there were a few errors mentioned on the lambda expression. I kindly appreciate your help as I am the 'new comers' of using Android Studio. Thank you.

Below (in the picture) is my code that is having errors regarding the lambda expression:

[image]

Comment: which types of error are you getting?

Comment: thank you ved prakash for your response, actually i am not really sure with the errors, based on the android studio, it mentioned that 'lambda expression was not expected here'. maybe it is regarding the symbol (->) that is have in my code. TQ

Comment: It should help you [How to enable Lambda in Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html), try to check both link
 [another link](https://mayojava.github.io/android/java/using-java8-lambda-expressions-in-android/)